# How to add an argument to a view programmatically?

Tags: 6, views

I want to add an argument to a view. I want to set this argument programmatically (not by url).

The field i want to filter is not directly in the view query, because this is a field on a node reference, so I cannot use `hook_views_query_alter`.

How can i can add programmatically an argument to a view?
I mean, which hook is better to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`hook_views_pre_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/docs%21docs.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/6.x-3.x) and set arguments you want.

```php
function hook_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  if ($view->name == 'your_view_name') {
    $view->set_arguments(array('arg1', 'arg2'));
  }
}
```